# Checkstyle error - Return count is 4 (max allowed is 2)

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am not sure if this is a duplicate question.

I have a Java method with 4 return statements, Each return statement is returning a different HTTP status.

How to fix this checkstyle error to reduce the return statements.

```
if (condition) {
return new ResponseEntity<Domain>(domain, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            } else if (condition2) {
return new ResponseEntity<Domain>(domain, HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
            } else {
return new ResponseEntity<Domain>(domain, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: First of all, what's the HTTP operation you are trying to accomplish to return that Spring's `ResponseEntity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an `HttpStatus` and then use just a single return statement:

```
HttpStatus status;
if (condition) {
    status = HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
else if (condition2) {
    status = HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED;
else {
    status = HttpStatus.OK;
}

return new ResponseEntity<Domain>(domain, status);
```